# Flutter project build failed with an exception

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I don't know why this is happening, it was working fine yesterday.

it is the error-

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-core:[1.21.0].
     Required by:
         project :app > io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.21.0
      > Failed to list versions for io.grpc:grpc-core.

<a lot more, didn't posted it>
```

here is my dependencies.

```
cloud_firestore: ^0.13.7
firebase_core: ^0.4.5
firebase_auth: ^0.16.1
```

Please help me out, it's so frustating, I literally didn't even change one line of code and this error popped up!

Comment: Run `flutter doctor` and check if there is something wrong.

Comment: it shows no issues

Comment: I think that this Github [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/56861) could help you !